# Keep Firefox sidebar links in the sidebar

Tags: firefox, sidebar

I've created a bookmark in Firefox that links to a hosted web application I've written and displays the application in the sidebar using the "Load this bookmark in the sidebar" option.

When the application appears in the sidebar and I click links there, those links open in the current Firefox tab rather than staying in the sidebar.  I would like the linked page to appear in the sidebar.

I'm hoping there's a simple solution, like setting the default target via a base tag, but I can't find a reference that gives me the information I need.  It would be useful if the solution does not limit the application to the sidebar exclusively, and still lets the application run full-window.

Answer (score 3):

I think all you need to do is link, or add target="_self"

Comment: The link will open in the sidebar if it has an onclick handler, if it is a data: or javascript: URL, or if it has a target (except _main or _content). Otherwise it will open in the browser. Unfortunately you can't set a base target to override this.

Answer (score 0):

This may be more a potential workaround than a real answer, but you could try using javascript to change document.location to the new URL. Something like:

```
<a href="javascript:document.location='http://whatever'>click me</a>
```

This would use the same 'window' object to display the new page and should load in the sidebar.